# QTimer doesn´t call the method to animate a plot

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pyqt5, qthread

I'm trying to create a GUI Application in PyQt5 that receives data continuously from a  remote GUI and plot an animination using pyqtgraph.
I'm using Python socket module for the connection and transfer data. I'm using multithreading for GUI and the connection.

The GUI and the reception of data works fine but when processing the data received to plot, the Qtimer doesn't call the method that makes the animation.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import socket 
from threading import Thread 
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn 
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi('app.ui', self)       
        self.plotWidget.plotItem.showGrid(True, True, 0.2)
        self.serverThread=ServerThread()
        self.serverThread.start()

    def plot(self, amplitude):
        self.y = amplitude * np.random.normal(size=600)
        self.plotWidget.setXRange (0, 2)
        self.plotWidget.setYRange (-0.5, 1)
        Color = pg.mkPen('g', width=1)
        self.curve = self.plotWidget.plot(self.y, pen=Color)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(20)

    #method that performs the animation
    def update(self):
        self.y[:-1] = self.y[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
        self.curve.setData(self.y)

class ServerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.window=window

     def run(self): 
        TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0' 
        TCP_PORT = 5000 
        BUFFER_SIZE = 20  
        tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
        tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)) 
        threads = [] 

        tcpServer.listen(1) 
        while True:
            print("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections from TCP clients..") 
            global conn
            (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpServer.accept() 
            newthread = ClientThread(ip,port) 
            newthread.start() 
            threads.append(newthread) 

        for t in threads: 
            t.join()

class ClientThread(Thread): 
    def __init__(self,ip,port): 
        Thread.__init__(self) 
        self.ip = ip 
        self.port = port 
        print("[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port))

    def run(self):        
        while True :             
            global conn
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            data_recv = data.decode('utf-8')
            data = int (data_recv)
            window.plot(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)        
    window = Window()
    window.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The GUI show the plot without the animation. What may the problem be? Are the processes being blocked? QTimer in QThread is being garbage collected? What am I doing wrong?

If someone has an idea, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are directly calling `window.plot(data)` from a thread that is not the main/GUI thread, and expecting the QTimer to then work to call a slot-method in the main/GUI thread.

Qt doesn't work that way, though -- if you want a `QTimer` to work in the main thread, you need to create it in the main thread.

A second problem is that you are creating a new `QTimer` in each call to `window.plot(data)`, and setting each new `QTimer` to emit a signal every 20mS.  So even if the `QTimer` functionality was working, the steady accumulation of dozens/hundreds of `QTimer` objects each emitting a signal 50 times a second would quickly swamp your program into uselessness.

My suggestion for a fix is to create just one single `QTimer` object (maybe inside `Window.__init__(self)`), `connect()` it to your `update()` slot, and call `start(20)` on it exactly once; that will be enough to get your `self.update()` method to be called at 50Hz (CPU power permitting).

That leaves only the question of how to safely transmit the received `data` from your networking-thread to your main thread.  For that, probably the easiest way is to create a subclass of `QEvent` that can hold your received `data` as a member variable, and have your networking-thread create a new object of that subclass each time it needs to send `data` to the main thread, and call `QApplication.postEvent()` with your `Window` and that `QEvent`-object as an argument.  Then in your `Window` class, override the `event(self, QEvent)` method (which is called whenever any event is received by your Window object) and add logic there so that if the event-argument is one of your event-subclass, it grabs the `data` out of the event and handles it.  (The critical advantage here is that `event(self, QEvent)` gets called by the main thread, not directly by your networking-thread, therefore you can safely interact with main-thread/GUI objects from within that context)